# compare using like operator in mysql is not working

Tags: mysql

The mysql query I tried is

```
SELECT 'a? b?' like 'a b'
```

Currently the output is 0. How do I make the result 1?

Comment: what are you trying to do??

Comment: compare a? b? with a b.and i need it to be matched

Comment: Check this http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/beyond-the-like-operator-advanced-pattern-matching-with-mysql.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need is only to match it. You must change `like` to `not like`.

```
SELECT 'a? b?' not like 'a b'
```

Result will be 1.

**EDIT**

You need to add `%`.

```
SELECT 'a? b?' like '%a%b%'
```

Comment: your target is to make it 1 using like? right? check edited post